# iPhone in-call status bar size?

Tags: ios4, statusbar, ios5, iphone-sdk-3.2

Does anyone know the size of the in-call status bar?
I am developing an app to be mostly used when the phone is in a call and would like to make the UI so it is usable while the in-call status bar is on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best thing to do would be to sign up for notifications for UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification .  the notification you receive will tell you the size of the status bar, so that you have the right thing now, the right thing when you rotate to landscape, the right thing when apple changes the size of the status bar, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The app will not be able to rotate, it will be a portrait only app.

Comment: even without rotation, when the size of the status bar changes due to an incoming phone call, the notification you receive will help you know that you need to change the display parameters of your on-screen items, and then also again if the call ends.  (i was just saying it would also do the right thing when doing rotation.)